# Is channel always writable after flush?

Tags: netty

I noticed that `outboundBuffer.addFlush()` calls `decrementPendingOutboundBytes`, and that decrese the number of outbound bytes in the ChannelOutBoundBuffer. So if i use `writeAndFlush`, will the channel become unwritable like use `write`? Or it will be always writable?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're a little bit confused with `Channel` and it's underlying outbound/inbound buffers. In short, each `Channel` represents a socket connection. And each socket connection has inbound (for receiving data) and outbound (for sending data) buffers.

`Channel` could be non writable but it means that the data will queued to `Channel`'s outbound buffer until the client could read it.

See `Channel.isWritable()` from the docs:

```
Returns true if and only if the I/O thread will perform the requested write operation immediately. Any write requests made when this method returns false are queued until the I/O thread is ready to process the queued write requests.
```

https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#isWritable--

So technically you can write to the non writable `Channel`. But it may lead to the server backpressure if the client consumes data much slower than the server write.